# Blender multiple animations and Collada export

Tags: blender, collada

Say I have a simple mesh in Blender, with two keyframes, like so:

[image: Left right keyframe 1]
[image: Left right keyframe 2]

Then, another animation for the same mesh, also with two keyframes:

[image: Up down keyframe 1]
[image: Up down keyframe 2]

Theese animations worke fine in Blender and I can switch between them in the Dopesheet, where they are called "actions":

[image: Dopesheet]

The problem arises, when i try to export this to the Collada format, for use in my game engine. The only animation/action that seems to be carried over, is the one currently associated to the mesh. Is it possible to export multiple animations/actions for the same mesh, to the Collada format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Collada exporter in blender does not support what Collada calls "animation clips", so only the current animation will be exported. You have a few options I can think of:

1. Fix the exporter (or convince someone to do it for you).
2. Write a script that loops through the actions and exports a new file for each action.
3. Use the NLA editor to create a track that has all the actions in sequence.
4. Export to another format that is easier to work with.

Obviously the first choice would be most appreciated by everyone else coming across this problem in the future.

Comment: Good points. Collada has been working quite nice for me (except this hickup). Though, any other formats you think are worth a look?

Comment: That all depends on what your game engine can do. IQM/IQE is a solid choice for simple assets with skeletal animation. The simplicity of the format makes it easy to write importers, exporters, and batch editing scripts. Unreal PSK/PSA are another solid option.

Answer (score 0):

since i'm not using blender i can only guess :)

but i think you would have to "bake" it into one single action, say you have the first animation from frame 1 to 10 
and the second animation frame 20 to 30 or something and then define in the game engine where to start and stop!

sebastian, xsheetgames

Comment: That would probably work, but it would be a very cumbersome solution...